# Logic behind calling function by using "Pointer to a function"

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-pointer

Suppose there is a pointer `f` declared to some function say `int foo(int)` as :

```
int (*f)(int)=foo;
```

While mentioning about calling `foo()` function by using this ponter which is passed as argument to some other function.
I have come across a statement saying that both

`y=(*f)(x)` and

`y=f(x)`

are same in C and calls function `foo()`....(x and y are of int type).

For arrays I know that if p is pointer to any array a.

`p[i]=*(p+i)=*(&a[0]+i)=*(a+i)=a[i]`.

So writing `p[i]` and `*(p+i)` are same thing. But I won't get the logic for "pointer to function" case. How `y=(*f)(x)` and `y=f(x)` are same? Is there any formula to understand this as it is there in case of "pointer to arrays" ?

Comment: It does not require formula to understand it.

Comment: So Is it just a rule that I have to remember?

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators 4
The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is
a function designator [...] 6.3 Conversions 6.3.2 Other operands 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators 4 A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the
operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, 65) or the unary & operator, a
function designator with type ‘‘function returning type’’ is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’.*

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude As my standard citation shows, you have it backwards. A function designator is converted to `pointer to function` before being called. See n1570: *6.5.2.2 Function calls 1 The expression that denotes the called function 92) shall have type pointer to function
returning void or returning a complete object type other than an array type.*

Answer (score 4):

Pre-ANSI C used to required that you dereference function pointers before calling them.

When C was getting standardized, people figured out there wasn't much you could do with a function pointer except call it (pointer arithmetic doesn't make sense on function pointers -- function pointers point to blocks of assembly instructions the length of which depends on the concrete function, not on the functions type. That is also the reason you can't have arrays of functions) so `f(x)` was made equivalent to `(*f)(x)` (or even `(****f)(x)` or `(**&**f)(x)` and various other combinations) as long as `f` is either a function or a singly-indirect function pointers (if it's a pointer to a function pointer, you need at least one `*` and so on for multiply indirect pointers).